# Web-Development: to which category do "Tabs" belong?

Tags: website-design, web-app

Browsing [this documentation](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/) I was surprised to see that Syncfusion have documented their Tab-Control in the "**Navigation**"-Category. I did not expect to find it there and was looking in "**Layout**".

My reasoning is that tabs are not used to navigate (in the sense of activating other pages), but they simply structure content, so you might use them to activate different sections of the same page.

But what is the thinking behind structuring web-controls in this way? *(Ok, I know, you are not Syncfusion - but I wonder if I am missing or misunderstanding some general concepts here...)*

Comment: One example, look at the top right of this site with "Questions, Tags, Users,..." those are designed to be tabs (style a bit less traditionally but you can see where the page connects to it), yet it navigates to new page on each of them.

Comment: Hmm, ok - yeah, I may buy that. ;-)   Syncfusion in their endless wisdom however only use it in the "classic" sense I described @ http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/tab/defaultfunctionalities

Comment: Yeah it definitely depends on how you use, and in my opinion should only be used for layout. But can be made to work as navigation in some places. Hopefully someone will have a good answer as to when/where it works in which way.

Comment: This question is probably too opinion-based for you to get a solid answer (besides, it seems your mind is probably made up already) but for what it's worth, I consider tabs to be navigation because they help users build a mental model of the system, find the information they need, and "go" to it.

Comment: The main reason for asking was that a co-dev suggested a categorization close to SF's ideas - so I was wondering if this will be "intuitive" for others that will have to use these categories or if more ppl would agree to place it elsewhere. I'll probably leave it alone now - unless someone has convincing arguments for "Layout"...

Comment: I also asked SF about in their forum ( http://www.syncfusion.com/forums/121901/categorization-of-controls-why-is-quottabquot-in-navigation ) and it seems they will be changing that ;-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question has been answered in the comments to the question.